# How to show a photo on full screen?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android and please help me how to show the uploaded photo in the FullScreen Activity.
I tried several methods but when I clicked on the photo it went to the screen but did not show the photo. Please write me the answer perfectly.

**ImageActivity.java**

It is my acivity where I have used *OnItemClickListener* method

```
  mRecyclerView = `findViewById`(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mUploads=new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new 
        GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

       mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                mUploads.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                    mUploads.add(upload);
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mDatabaseRef.removeEventListener(mDBListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

     
    }
}
```

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;



    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mContext = context;
        mUploads = uploads;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;


        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);

        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener){
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly set the listener to send data to a new activity:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,FullImageActivity.class);
        intent .putExtra("img",url);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

then set FullImageActivity to receive data and show image, then set style to full screen

```
         <activity
            android:name=".FullImageActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
```

style:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
</style>
```